# Stop detecting Input in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

How can I stop detecting input from the user in Unity? I want to achieve the following: "do not detect `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`" In C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do not call the input query function if you don't want any user input. Something like this:

```
class InputExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool EnableInput = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if( EnableInput )
        {
            var mousedown = Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);

            if( mousedown )
            {
                Debug.Log("Mouse button pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now just change the `EnableInput` variable to false to disable input detection.

Comment: yup that was simple :P